# using advanced targeting with codeigniter parse library

Tags: php, codeigniter, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using this php library https://github.com/st028/codeigniter-parse.com-library 
and I want to use advanced targeting. But There is no "ParseInstallation" in this library.So I cant use it. 
Is there any way to use advanced targeting?

Comment: Try installing via composer https://getcomposer.org/ then added to yor libraries folder in codeigniter

Comment: I am already using the library and my question; is there another parse library to use with codeigniter which has parse installation?